# How to use Eclipse JDT to indent code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have a lot of methods code stored in database. They all have tabs/spaces on the left of each line, like the following. Because they are extracted by using JDT ASTParser.

[image]

I want to shift left one unit, which would make the code like the following. It removes spaces on left but still indent correctly for code inside the method.

[image]

We can do that in eclipse by "shift+tab", but how to do it using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.IndentManipulation to query/modify the indentation of a specific piece of code.  Hopefully you won't have to parse the code using AST.